# C++ function that returns a value, need help in optimization

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, reference

I am learning C++ and I have written the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<int, vector<uint8_t>> m;

vector<uint8_t> getBitVec(int id)
{
        unordered_map<int, vector<uint8_t>>::const_iterator it = m.find(id);
        if (it != m.cend()) {
                return it->second;
        }
        return vector<uint8_t>();
}

void aND(vector<uint8_t>& dst, const vector<uint8_t>& src)
{
        for (auto i = 0U; i != dst.size(); i++) {
                dst[i] = dst[i] & src[i];
        }
}

// Get a resultant vector of line_item ids from a bit vector of line items
vector<uint16_t> getVec(const vector<uint8_t>& s)
{
        vector<uint16_t> result;
        for (auto i = 0U; i != s.size(); i++) {
                uint8_t temp = (1<<7);
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                        if (s[i] & (temp >> j)) {
                                result.push_back(i * 8 + j);
                        }
                }
        }
        return result;
}


vector<uint16_t> find2(const vector<int>& k)
{
        vector<uint8_t> result;
        bool flag = true;

        for (auto i = 0U; i != k.size(); i++) {
                const vector<uint8_t>& v = getBitVec(k[i]);
                if (v.empty()) {
                        return vector<uint16_t>();
                }
                if (flag == true) {
                        //result = move(v);
                        result = v;
                        flag = false;
                        continue;
                }
                aND(result, v);
        }
        return getVec(result);
}

void init()
{
        m[1].push_back(0xff);
        m[1].push_back(0xfe);

        m[2].push_back(0xf8);
        m[2].push_back(0xf9);

        m[3].push_back(0xf1);
        m[3].push_back(0xf2);
}

int main()
{
        init();
        const auto& t = find2(vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
        for (auto i = 0U; i != t.size(); i++) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n%d\n", t[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Basically I want to write a function which either returns a reference to a non-local "heavy" object or a copy of the empty object.

The function I am implementing is `getBitVec` (as in the URL).
Can someone tell if the `aND` will operate on a "temporary copy" of the vector returned or no copy will be created.

I believe that `aND` function will operate on the copy and I want to get away with the overhead of copy as clearly, the code doesn't need a copy. But can I do this without changing the interface of `getBitVec`?

This is not a puzzle or hypothetical question and I am not looking for tricks like storing a sentinel key in "m" (with value = vector()) and returning the reference to it, thereby changing the signature to
vector& getBitVect(const vector&)

Is this code idiomatic in C++11?

Do I have no choice but to use pointer as return type for `getBitVec`?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The title is confusing, I meant "Value" not reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a const reference, instead of returning copy of an empty object, you can create a static local instance of the empty object in the function (so it is created once first time function is called and stays alive until the program terminates), and return reference to this static empty object.

If you intend to return non-const reference (the caller of the function may modify the object), then it is best to return pointer to the object instead of reference, and nullptr if object is not found.

```
const vector<uint8_t>& getBitVec(int id)
{
        unordered_map<int, vector<uint8_t>>::const_iterator it = m.find(id);
        if (it != m.cend()) {
                return it->second;
        }
        static const vector<uint8_t> empty_vec;
        return empty_vec;
}
```

Or

```
vector<uint8_t>* getBitVec(int id)
{
        unordered_map<int, vector<uint8_t>>::const_iterator it = m.find(id);
        if (it != m.cend()) {
                return &(it->second);
        }
        return nullptr;
}
```